# Java: possible locations for "import" statement

Tags: java, syntax

Edit: this does not make sense. `import` cannot be used in any way to restrict package access.

By default, we write the `import a.b.SomeClass;` statements at the top of each java file below the package name.

Is it in any way possible to use the `import` statement later in the code?

> Background: we need to implement an interface for dynamic code injection. We want to make it as safe/secure as possible. The idea was to restrict the imported packages, but this would only make sense if there is no (easy) way to use this statement later in the code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html

Comment: Please explain how do you want to make "an interface for dynamic code injection" safe/secure" by restricting the imported packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any class without importing them by using their Fully Qualified Name, i.e. `com.evil.BadClass` instead of `import com.evil.*;`.

This makes the whole import thing irrelevant. It's just for making development easier and it can't be used as a security control.

If you're looking to secure things, look into [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html), as well as make sure you have skilled people who know about security aspects. If this question represents the skill level of security and Java knowledge you have, you will need outside help.

Comment: Of course, you are correct. We are just gathering ideas ;).

Comment: If you're serious about security, it's not really a "let's gather some ideas" kind of situation.

Comment: I guess it depends on the environment. In our case, only few people will have access to this functionality. So it is more of a safety rather than security thing.

Comment: `We want to make it as safe/secure as possible.`. You said that. I don't really care, just don't fool yourself if you implement some unverified custom security.

Answer (score 3):

As per [JLS §7.3. Compilation Units](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) import declaration comes after package declaration, before type declaration:

> CompilationUnit:
>   [PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}

Then it is possible to use `SomeClass` by fully-qualified class name `a.b.SomeClass` without import declaration.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Import statements are very much a property given to the current .java file, rather than an instruction to be taken into account at the place or time it is encountered.

You cannot put them elsewhere, and it wouldn't matter if you could as what they mean is irrelevant to their location.